# Click Limiting on <button>

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to make it so that you can't press an  button more than 3 times per second using JavaScript and onclick. Here is my website: http://clickthebutton.herokuapp.com/.

My button's code:

```
<button id="button" type="button" onclick="loadXMLDoc();">click</button>
```

My rate-limiter:

```
function doSomething() {
setTimeout('document.getElementById("button").disabled=false;', 1000);
}
```

^ not working.

If the button is pressed more than 3 times per second, I'd like to run a function. Please could I have some help with this!

-William

Comment: You have to put some code...

Comment: Yes, here is what you have to do: whenever the button is clicked more than 3 times, run a function.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's my solution, really simple:

HTML:

```
<button onclick="rateLimit()">Click me!</button>
```

JS:

```
var counter = 0;
function rateLimit()
{
    counter++;
    if (counter == 3)
    {
        alert('3 times in a second! - run a function!');
        //some code ...
        counter = 0;
    }  
}

setInterval(function() { counter = 0; }, 1000);
```

Working fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/z3s553m4/

Answer (score 2):

Here's a really simple example:

```
// onclick handler
function loadXMLDoc(el) {
    // Call rate limiter, passing element
    rateLimiter(el);
}

// IIFE - minimizes dem globals
var rateLimiter = (function() {

    // Our yummy private variables.
    var rate = 0;
    var rateLimiter;
    var rateLimitTime;
    var isRateLimited = false;

    // Our returned function that's called when we invoke our IIFE
    return function(el) {

        // We rate limiting yet? The ! says we ain't.
        if (!isRateLimited) {

            // INCREMENT!
            rate++;

            // Set our variable to true, we don't want a bunch of setTimeouts queued up...
            isRateLimited = true;

            // Runs after a second. Clears the disabled attribute and allows 
            // for additional rate limiting. Mmmm, throttling......
            rateLimiter = setTimeout(function() {
                rate = 0;
                isRateLimited = false;
                el.removeAttribute('disabled');
            }, 1000);
        }

        // OH, hello rate limiting. Let's start!
        else {
            // Increment and then check our val
            if (++rate >= 3) {
                // Oh sh*t, we at or over 3. DISABLE!
                el.setAttribute('disabled', 'disabled');
            }
        }
    };
}());
```

Here's a fiddle to demonstrate: http://jsfiddle.net/yja8c034/

(Note: I'm passing `this` in the `onclick` call)

(Note: This also doesn't require a timer running in the bg resetting a counter)

Answer (score 1):

you can have a counter that incrememnts everytime your onclick function is fired.

Then, have the function passed to `setTimeout` hold an if condition that will check your counter to see if it is 3 or more. If it is, then fire your desired function.

Either way, reset the counter to 0 at the end of the setTimeout, whose delay you can set to 1000 ms.