# Android: Changing and limiting button click

Tags: android

having some trouble getting 2 buttons to work.

In the screenshot below, I'm making 2 buttons called NEXT & BACK. And these buttons allows the user to change it from Week 1 to Week 3. When they click NEXT and reach Week , I need the button to disable and not allow them to proceed further since its only a max of 3 weeks. Same thing goes for the BACK button and cycling thru and reaching Week 1. See below also for my code.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/fLazK.jpg

```
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.media.Image;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity {

    final String PREFS_NAME = "MyPrefs";
    ViewPager viewPager;
    String week1 = "1";
    String week2 = "2";
    String week3 = "3";
    private int[] weekNumbers = {1, 2, 3};
    int weekNumberCounter = 0;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        //Casting variables

        viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
        viewPager.setAdapter(new MyAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager()));

        //////// First startup screen after first time use
        SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, 0);
        if (settings.getBoolean("my_first_time", true)) {


            Intent VirginBoot = new Intent(this, Begin_Program.class);
            startActivity(VirginBoot);

            // Record the fact that the app has been started at least once
            settings.edit().putBoolean("my_first_time", false).apply();
        }
    }


    public void settingsButton(View view) {

        Intent i = new Intent(this, Settings.class);
        startActivity(i);
    }


    public void NextWeek(View view) {
        int weekCounter = 0;
        TextView weekNumber = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.week_number_text);
        ImageButton LastWeekButton = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.LastWeek);
        ImageButton NextWeekButton = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.NextWeek);

        switch (view.getId()) {
            case R.id.NextWeek:

                if (weekCounter < (weekNumbers.length) - 2) {
                    weekCounter++;
                    weekNumber.setText(week2);


                    if (weekCounter == (weekNumbers.length) - 1) {

                        weekNumber.setText(week3);
                        LastWeekButton.setClickable(true);
                        NextWeekButton.setClickable(false);
                    }
                }


            case R.id.LastWeek:
                if (weekCounter > weekNumbers.length) {
                    weekCounter--;
                    weekNumber.setText(week2);

                    if (weekCounter == (weekNumbers.length) - 1) {
                        weekNumber.setText(week1);
                        NextWeekButton.setClickable(true);
                        LastWeekButton.setClickable(false);
                    }
                }
                break;


        }


    }


    class MyAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
        public MyAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
            super(fm);
        }

        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int arg0) {
            Fragment fragment = null;
            if (arg0 == 0) {
                fragment = new Day_1();
            }
            if (arg0 == 1) {
                fragment = new Day_2();
            }
            if (arg0 == 2) {
                fragment = new Day_3();
            }
            if (arg0 == 3) {
                fragment = new Day_4();
            }


            return fragment;
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return 4;
        }

    }

}
```

Maybe I'm looking in the wrong areas but I've tried the links below and they havent worked so far.

[How to disable button click?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4204017/how-to-disable-button-click)
[How to disable button as soon as its clicked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11031814/how-to-disable-button-as-soon-as-its-clicked)
[Click Limiting on <button>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31688571/click-limiting-on-button)

Comment: Your logic that determines when to disable and when to enable it is probably not correct.

Comment: post your xml layout also here

Answer (score 0):

First off, you should probably store your buttons as fields in your class instead of finding them each time your functions are called, finding them the first time in the activity onCreate() instead. Then, in the OnClick of your button, you can call setEnabled(false) on that button depending on whether the button should still be enabled.